# Trigger function when bottom of iframe reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that adjusts it's size dynamical. I solved this with a post message and a listener on the parent page, so everytime the content of the iframe changes the iframe size will too and there will never be a scroll bar.

In the iframe I am showing a list and everytime the bottom of the iframe is reached, I want to append new items to the list.

For me it would also work to trigger the function when the bottom of the parent page is reached, so i tried:

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();
```

**But it is forbidden due to cross domain origin.**

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: try passing a cross domain header with the iframe. The header looks something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.parentsite.com` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys.

I now solved it using postmessage. I actually thought it could only be used to post a message from the iframe to the parent, but it also works the other way.

So just add this code to the parent javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hotellist').contentWindow.postMessage("scroll", "*");
```

and then catch the post message in the iframe element with:

```
var myEventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var myEventListener = window[myEventMethod];
var myEventMessage =  myEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

myEventListener(myEventMessage, function (e) { 

    if (e.data === "scroll") {
        // Do whatever you want to do
    } 

}, false);
```